# Ubuntu won’t boot after deleting logs

Tags: boot

So the other day my logs filled my whole machine. I deleted them but then couldn’t open any apps and my WiFi card disappeared. I restarted and now can’t boot and just get a blinking “_”. I attempted to boot holding “ESC” but keep getting “Failed to start D-Bud system message bus”. I have no console at all.

Video: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/738362110878416917/988844437964750868/IMG_8042.mov

Comment: Which files did you delete exactly?

Comment: @cocomac every file in /var/logs

Comment: @user535733 sh my mistake I meant /var/log

Comment: Boot from a LiveUSB. Mount your hard drive. Look in your hard drive's /home directory for your username. Find your `.bash_history` file. The commands you used are at the bottom of that file. Copy the entire sequence of commands that you used (including all mistakes). Paste the sequence [into your question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1415105/edit). DO NOT edit or correct or skip anything. Merely deleting logs cannot prevent booting, so it's clear you did something else. There are typos in your Question and comments, which suggests that what you *actually* did might be different.